# How to convert Unixtimestamp to date

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am using a array where they use unixtimestamp, like 1421241074.
Any idea how to convert it to date? I know that strtotime is date to unixtimestamp and that is exactly what I don't want.

I am trying something like this at the moment:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) { //this works 
                        $timestamp = substr($value['timestamp'], 6, 13); //this works
                        $timestamp = ('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp); // this supose to convert unixtimestamp to date. fail!
```

but this is not working, someone here with a idea?

Comment: $timestamp = **date** ('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `date()` php function:

```
date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

In your code you forgot the `date` part of `date()`!

Comment: Tnx for your answer, got it :) only that he return 03/07/1957 wich is not even possible ^^ I will try to get this debugged, once again.. Tyvm! I had no clue!

Comment: Sounds like your timestamp is incorrect... good luck solving that part of it!

Comment: I guess it is, even as it is from a api! Will try my best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Try to read about the timestamp function, in the documentation you should see about converting unix.